# Error handling in AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate

Tags: ios, avfoundation, frame-rate, avurlasset, fairplay

What is the recommended way for handling error in AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate? specifically network requests in `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` / `shouldWaitForRenewalOfRequestedResource`?

However, there is no way for my app to know something went wrong until I start playing the video. I tried `loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: err)` and `return false` in the `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` delegate call, but nothing was reported until the download finishes and the user starts playing the video.

the code goes like this..

```
let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)  
asset?.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true  
asset?.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self.fairPlayAssetLoaderDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)) // fairPlayAssetLoaderDelegate is an object that implements AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate  
// send urlAsset to AVAssetDownloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask
```

after setting `preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true`, it seems like `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` is called right away after setting the resource loader delegate in AVURLAsset. but there is no way to tell the resource loader has successfully got all the information it wants.

I tried using `loadValuesAsynchronously` on AVURLAsset, but that's a no go either.

AVAssetDownloadURLSession doesn't always report the error either..

Thanks in advance.